# How to run normal session from user script after passing init=MY_SCRIPT in grub entry

Tags: grub2, python, init

I have entry in grub to start my configuration script written in Python.
I would like to give user option to start normal session after the work is done. 
But I've found that /sbin/init needs to have PID==1, so when I run in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "exec /sbin/init 2"])
#subprocess.call("exec /sbin/init 2", shell=True)
```

-it ends with:

> init: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection
>   refused

and kernel panic

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: One possible solution is to run bash script like this:
    #!/bin/bash;
    MY_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py;
    exec /sbin/init 2;
but it isn't very nice workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exec ( os.execv ) init, not run it as a subprocess.
Like this:
`os.execv('/sbin/init', ['/sbin/init'])`